# Confusion with sending email in Django

Tags: django

My Django app needs to send emails in HTML format. As per the [official documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs):

> It can be useful to include multiple versions of the content in an
>   email; the classic example is to send both text and HTML versions of a
>   message. With Django's email library, you can do this using the
>   EmailMultiAlternatives class. This subclass of EmailMessage has an
>   attach_alternative() method for including extra versions of the
>   message body in the email. All the other methods (including the class
>   initialization) are inherited directly from EmailMessage.

...I came up with the following code:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives()
msg.sender = "someone@somewhere.com"
msg.subject = subject
msg.to = [target,]
msg.attach_alternative(content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

This work as expected. However, in some situations I need to include PDF attachments, for which I added the following code just before `msg.send()`:

```
if attachments is not None:
    for attachment in attachments:
        content = open(attachment.path, 'rb')
        msg.attach(attachment.name,content.read(),'application/pdf')
```

Although this works - all PDF documents are properly attached to the email - the unwanted side effect is that the HTML content of the email now has disappeared and I'm left with an empty email body with PDF documents attached to it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try setting the application type to text instead of application, and let me know how this would change anything.

Comment: @securecurve: The only change is that the attachments are no longer PDF documents but plain text documents. The email body is still empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EmailMultiAlternatives is to be used, if you want to provide both plain text and text/html version. Than its up to the email client of the recipient to decide which version to display. What you need is simply:

```
from django.core import mail

....

msg = mail.EmailMessage(subject, content,
                        to=[target], from_email='someone@somewhere.com')
if attachments is not None:
    for attachment in attachments:
        msg.attach_file(attachment, 'application/zip')
```

Comment: Thanks, but that fails in message.py in sanitize_address, line 102: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Hmm.. this seems like something that could happen is email address is wrong... What value did you use for target ?

Comment: Ah, right, from_email needs to be one address not a list. I've fixed the code sample in the response. Does it work for you now?

Comment: Partly. The variable "content" contains HTML formatted text which is now displayed as unformatted content in the email body. The attachments are properly attached. As I need a properly formatted HTML message, the EmailMultiAlternatives appears the only way.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out.

If you use `EmailMultiAlternatives` you apparently MUST supply both the text format and the HTML format of the body of the email for situations where your email has additional attachments. I only supplied the HTML format which was ok for an email without attachments but somehow was confusing when other attachments were added like PDF documents.

The final working code:

```
text_content = strip_tags(content)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives()
msg.sender = "someone@somewhere.com"
msg.subject = subject
msg.to = [target]
msg.body = text_content
msg.attach_alternative(content, "text/html")
if attachments is not None:
    for attachment in attachments:
        content = open(attachment.path, 'rb')
        msg.attach(attachment.name,content.read(),'application/pdf')
msg.send()
```

Comment: can you supply reference to why you must supply *both* text body and html alternative?

Comment: Doesn't work @Roger Still html content is getting overriden